# Unable to see the screenshot in the extent report on others machine using hooks concept

Tags: selenium, cucumber-junit, extentreports, webpage-screenshot

When I am sending the extent-report to other person screenshot is missing from the report and i have tried every ways zipped the report and send it but same issues was there. I have implemented in Cucumber framework by using hooks concept in that I have used robot class.So,please anyone can help me out.

Comment: It would be nice if you share the the code that you have written for setting up extent and taking screenshots. It might be possible that you are using a different folder for your screenshots and when you send the extent-report or try to open it on different machine, the path gets broken hence you don't see images.

Comment: hey @Ayaz - here is the code

Comment: You might want to read through the [tour] and [ask] to get a better idea of how this site works, so that you can get the answer you are after.

Answer (score 0):

```
 *package stepDefinitions;

import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
//import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
//import java.util.Base64;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;


import com.cucumber.listener.Reporter;

import cucumber.api.Scenario;
import cucumber.api.java.After;
import cucumber.api.java.Before;

public class Hook 
{
    @Before(" @TC001")
    public void setup() {
        
        Reporter.assignAuthor("QA - Gunjan Attri");

        System.out.println("open");
    }

    @After("@TC001")
    public static void tearDown(Scenario scenario) {
        if (scenario.isFailed()) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Test case which got failed is " + scenario.getName());
                Robot awt_robot = new Robot();
                BufferedImage Entire_Screen = awt_robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
                String Destination = "D:\\OFFICE\\Office Project\\office\\HermesCucumberBDD\\screenshots\\"+scenario.getName()+".png";
                //ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                ImageIO.write(Entire_Screen, "PNG", new File(Destination));
                //encodedData = Base64.encodeBase64(outStream.toByteArray());

                Reporter.addScreenCaptureFromPath(Destination);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            try {
                System.out.println("Test case which got passed is " + scenario.getName());
                Robot awt_robot = new Robot();
                BufferedImage Entire_Screen = awt_robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
                String Destination = "D:\\OFFICE\\Office Project\\office\\HermesCucumberBDD\\screenshots\\"+scenario.getName()+".png";
                ImageIO.write(Entire_Screen, "PNG", new File(Destination));
                Reporter.addScreenCaptureFromPath(Destination);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    
}*
```

Comment: This is not an answer. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63243973/edit) your original question with this information.